# Main camera only see the ground

Tags: unity-game-engine

I make a 3d game.My gun only shoot the ground , even when I select other object to shoot. I have the ground at a rotation , it may affects the game? Should I add something to the main camera?

```css
using UnityEngine;

public class Gun : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float damage = 10f;
    public float range = 100f;
    public Camera fpsCam;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
 

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Shoot();

        }
        
    }
    void Shoot()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
       if( Physics.Raycast(fpsCam.transform.position, fpsCam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
        {
            Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
        }
    }
}
```

[picture ground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asbEJ.png)

Comment: Do your other objects have a collider attached? Have you tried to use [`Debug.DrawRay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawRay.html) to visualize your ray?

Comment: what I should declare in void DrawRay() { }

Comment: Do you have any `Collider` components on the objects you would like to detect hits on? Also, what `Layer` is selected on the objects you would like to shoot?

Comment: Yes , the cub has the BoxCollider and the ground same , they have the same layer Default

Comment: `what I should declare in void DrawRay() { }`. Please, take some time to read the documentation page I've linked.....

Comment: @Hellium https://paste.pics/eb59282dad04baee440562d20a893add